# SVN & VS.NET 2003 - Anyway to run without modified TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, git, visual-studio-2003

We've just inherited a massive client project that is in VS.NET 2003.  We typically use SVN and I installed and put the code into SVN.  It's been 5-6 years since I've had to deal with the issue that VS.NET web projects don't deal well with folders that start with ".".

I used the modified tortoise version in the past, but we have not used that in years.  I'm wondering what my options are?  Is there a way around this without upgrading or do I need to try a different source code repository?  I looked into Git and it looks pretty good, but the GUI's are only for 2K5/2K8 which is cool, but not helping me.

I don't want to try and convert this massive (thousands of code files) project to a class library project, which someone may suggest as a solution.

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: TortoiseSVN > Settings > General > Use "_svn" instead of ".svn" directories

git is great but I don't think a polished interface like TortoiseSVN is available yet.

Edit: May have spoke too soon on the polished interface. As spidey noted, [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) is available.

Comment: Jesse, that will work, but will be a bit painful because I'll have to remember to switch between the two when working on normal projects.  But it will work, so thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's much of a downside to just leaving this option on, if that's easiest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Would the VisualSVN plugin be of any use?  You don't need the VisualSVN server (which is nice in its own right), but the client piece may be helpful (can't remember if it supports VS2003 or not).

Comment: VisualSVN is nice and supports VS2003 but it won't help you as it's simply another svn client (relies even on TortoiseSVN), which means it uses the .svn (or _svn) administrative directory just as any other svn client